# Url is changing, but content is not updating

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routing

I have a  angular 8 application. And some items with id's. The good thing is that if you select a item the url will change. But the actual item will not change. So what I mean with that I have some items under each other with each item an unique id. If you click the first time on a item you will see the correct item. But if you click then on a other item, the previous item will been shown and not the actual item, but the url is changing.

the url is for example like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/2cdc2f5b-e9ff-4fbd-a1a6-30a2e357d69b
```

and other id is like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/6bc0331b-7577-4d2c-8d02-a8a090adea82
```

So I have this as link for the item:

```
  <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item', item.id]" i18n-title title="Edit">
          <mat-icon>editggg</mat-icon>
        </a>
```

and this I have for the routing:

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'item/:dossierItemId', component: ItemComponent },
      { path: 'item/new/:dossierItemType', component: ItemComponent },
    ],
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
```

and this is the ts of the component:

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  dossier: DossierDto;
  dossierItems: DossierItemDto[] = [];
  itemSearchMatches = {};
  typeSearchMatches = {};
  formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
  editDossierForm: FormGroup;
  globalEditDossierErrors: ValidationErrors;
  itemTypes = DossierItemTypeDto;
  searchQueryHolder = '';
  // @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup;
  selectedTabIndex: number;
  selectedTab = 0;
  showTemplate = false;

  constructor(
    private dossierService: DossierService,
    private uiStateService: UIStateService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private errorProcessor: ErrorProcessor

  ) {
    this.dossier = route.snapshot.data.dossier;
    this.dossierItems = route.snapshot.data.dossierItems;
    this.searchDossieritems(null);
    this.editDossierForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.name, [Validators.required])
    });
    this.editDossierForm.disable();
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
     const state = this.uiStateService.getState();
     if (state) {
      this.selectedTab = state.tabState || 0; //If there is no state
    }
     this.setTabState(state.tabState);
/*
     this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.itemTypes.ActionStep = params['itemTypes.ActionStep'];
    }); */

  }
```

So what I have to change? Thank you

This is my app.routing.module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I try it like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

But this doesnt work. So the content is not changing

like this:

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldDetach(route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  store(route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: import("@angular/router").DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  shouldAttach(route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  retrieve(route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot): import("@angular/router").DetachedRouteHandle {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false; // default is true if configuration of current and future route are the same
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: So the url of the id is changing but the item is not changing. So you will not navigate to the correct item.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker example, at that time I can help you!

Comment: In app.module.ts file you need to add `onSameUrlNavigation` property for Router config. So the code will be like `@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })`

Comment: @RanjithS. No it doesnt. It doesnt updated  the item

Comment: @RanjithS. Do you have other suggestion?

Comment: I too had the same issue before and it worked for me after i used this code. Will update here if i find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be useful:

In your app.module.ts, add this in providers.

```
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy }
```

```js
export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: {}): void {

  }
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): {} {
    return null;
  }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false; // default is true if configuration of current and future route are the same
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you . But then I also need all the methods. Because it is abstract class: RouteReuseStrategy

Comment: And I get lot of errors: core.js:6406 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Method not implemented.
Error: Method not implemented.

Comment: But never heard about RouteReuseStrategy I googled a lot. How did you found this?

Comment: I used this 3 years ago when I was working on angular 4. Not sure how I googled at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  location.subscribe(val => {
            console.log(val)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the route data event so that you can get the latest updated data came from your resolver

```
constructor(
  private dossierService: DossierService,
  private uiStateService: UIStateService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private errorProcessor: ErrorProcessor

) { 
  this.route.data.subscribe(() => {
    this.dossier = route.snapshot.data.dossier;
    this.dossierItems = route.snapshot.data.dossierItems;
    this.searchDossieritems(null);
    this.editDossierForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.name, [Validators.required])
    });
    this.editDossierForm.disable();
  });

}
```

To make your resolver re-run again add this `runGuardsAndResolvers`

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',
    children: [
      { path: 'item/:dossierItemId', component: ItemComponent },
      { path: 'item/new/:dossierItemType', component: ItemComponent },
    ],
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you of course. But nothing changes. I tried so many things.

Comment: Hi @savantTheCoder I added a solution to your route

Comment: thank you . I have that now. But also the first time it goes to the correct item, and when I select other item. it doesnt update. The soluiton was coming from other member. Just tried that and it works. But again of course thank you for your effort. But in this case other solution worked